# Instruments Automation Tool: Script Ended Without Explicitly Closing This Test

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I was playing around with the Automation tool in Instruments today but have had problems writing a working test. The following example will exit with `Issue: Script ended without explicting closing this test`. Yes, the message really does say *expliciting*. I assume this is a typo introduced in a recent version of Xcode. This is the first time I've tried using this tool. Setting `cellCount` to 6 results in a Pass but anything gives me the 'script ended' message. Am I doing it wrong or is there a bug with the Automation Tool.

```
UIALogger.logStart("Start Simple Test");
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var cellCount = 7;

UIALogger.logMessage("cell count: " + cellCount);

if (cellCount != 6) {
    UIALogger.logFail("Failed");
}

UIALogger.logPass("Passed");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is you are closing your log group incorrectly. When you say `logStart()`, you begin a log group in instruments and everything you log after that with `logMessage()` or `logError()` will be enclosed in that group.

You close groups with either `logFail()` or `logPass()` which it looks like you tried to do, but you can only call one or the other. You need an else clause in there to call `logPass()` like so:

```
if (cellCount != 6) {
    UIALogger.logFail("Failed");
} else {
    UIALogger.logPass("Passed");
}
```

Strangely, when I pasted your code snippet into UI Automation, I didn't get the issue error you mentioned. It just printed two log groups to the trace log. Try using the else clause like I mentioned above and see if it works.

Comment: Added the else clause but I'm still seeing the same behavior. If I reverse the if/else conditions and use a `==` test I still see the same behavior. However, if I insert a second innocuous logMessage after the first one then I get the proper pass/fail behavior. I have no idea why that would make a difference but it seems to. Having both if/else condition **does** make a difference as you mentioned. Going to mark this as answered even though it seems my installation/version is a bit unpredictable.

Comment: That's pretty confusing. Have you been experiencing any other oddities in Xcode or other Apple Dev tools? I wonder if something is wrong with your Xcode installation. Your reasoning is correct and I'm confused on why you're experiencing this behavior, too. I can't replicate it on my two dev machines.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the real issue here. It is basically saying that your app is not in usable mode to test further at specified point. So please either pass/fail or add appropriate delay at this place.

So easiest solution to avoid this is to have one delay function of 2 sec after each page navigation. That will load data in each page after fetching and displaying data on pano. And script will run smoothly.

//Step:1 Navigating/tapping

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
```

//verification

//Step: 2 Navigating/tapping

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(2);
```

//verification

Answer (score 0):

How odd. I'm experiencing this same issue precisely as described above and I am also using the `else` clause.

Also, I tried the double logging method as mentioned above like so, just before my `if` statement to log pass or fail:

```
UIALogger.logMessage("My Story Title: " + titleDisplayed);
UIALogger.logMessage("Innocuous Message.");
```

And got a FAIL, which is fine--I wanted anything other than the "`Issue`" result and the "`script ended without expliciting`" message. So, I then commented `//` the second `logMessage` statement and re-ran the test and this time got the "`Issue`" and "`script ended without explicating`" again.

So, his above tip has been verified as real.

I'm running Xcode and Instruments version 4.6 with the iPhone Emulator running as a 6.1 project.

---Update--

I cannot get pass/fail to work properly no matter what I do. On one run I get the enraging "`Issue: Script ended without explicating` " message in my log, and then if I make any changes to the script--even if it's just to add an extra whitespace, and save it and then run again--I'll get a good pass or fail result.

But if I then immediately run the test again without any changes at all I'll get the "`Issue: Script ended without explicating`" message and this will not go away until I make a meaningless change in the script and save and then run again and then MAYBE at this point I might get a decent pass/fail result (doesn't always happen), but if I run the script again I will get "`Issue: Script ended without explicating`" again.

What the heck? I've actually taken the time to reinstall Xcode 4.6 but no luck in getting the behavior to change. I'm profoundly frustrated. This appears to be a bug in Instruments. Is there a way to report this to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. You have to have the string you put on your logStart method in the logPass or logFail method too - that's all! Which would mean for example:

```
UIALogger.logStart("Add to Whishlist");
//here comes your automation code
UIALogger.logPass("Add to Whishlist");
```

You can open then another test with the `logStart()` and close it either with `logPass()` methods

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that if you place delays between the different messages, they actually show up and evaluate the problems. The issue I started with was, that two successive logMessages did not show up correctly (the last one being dropped)

```
UIALogger.logMessage("This is some text");
UIALogger.logMessage("This is some text");
//UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
```

only showed one output line. Uncommenting shows two... This seems somewhat... inconsistent - and there is more: (This goes to Wulf)

```
UIALogger.logStart("Add to Whishlist");
UIALogger.logMessage("My Story Title: ");
//UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
UIALogger.logMessage("Innocuous Message.");
//UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
if (true)
    UIALogger.logPass("Add to Whishlist");
else
    UIALogger.logFail("Add to Whishlist");
```

Here I got an "*issue*". Uncommenting helped to solve this. I know, this is no solution. But it worked as a workaround for me.

The "string" in the logStart, logFail or logPass did not matter for me actually.